# When using ctrl-f find I have trouble telling my currently highlighted result apart from the other results. How do I customize these colors?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> find, I have trouble telling my currently highlighted result apart from the other results. How do I customize these colors?

I've tried a bunch of different color themes and they absolutely change the color of highlights, but, they change both colors, so the result is always, two very similar colors.

I found the settings.json text I needed to wildly change the color of my scrollbars, but I have no clue what that might be for find highlighted results colors.

An old answer mentions `"editor.rangeHighlightBackground": "#ff0000"` but settings.json indicates this is not a currently valid vscode settings option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest it inside the `workbench.colorCustomizations` setting. Customize the following as desired in your settings.json file:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.findMatchBackground": "#880000",
    "editor.findMatchBorder": "#ff0000",
    "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#008800",
    "editor.findMatchHighlightBorder": "#00ff00",
    "editor.findRangeHighlightBackground": "#000088",
    "editor.findRangeHighlightBorder": "#0000ff",
}
```

And if you want ti to apply only for a specific colour theme, additionally wrap it in a `"[Name Of Theme]": { ... }` field, like:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai]": {
        "editor.findMatchBackground": "#880000",
        "editor.findMatchBorder": "#ff0000",
        "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#008800",
        "editor.findMatchHighlightBorder": "#00ff00",
        "editor.findRangeHighlightBackground": "#000088",
        "editor.findRangeHighlightBorder": "#0000ff",
    },
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver. I was gotta batty trying to keep my eyes on the right spot before!